# KnockoutJS computedObservable in ObservableArray

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Learning KnockoutJS and hit a brick wall. Making a calculator for a game. A summarized version is below:

User inputs 'neededXp'.
Array should recalculate 'need' everytime 'neededXp' is updated.

```
self.neededXp = ko.observable(0);

function calcItem(name, image, xp, level) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
    this.xp = xp;
    this.need = ko.computed(function() {
        var req = self.neededXp()/this.xp;
        return req;
    });
}

self.calcContent = ko.observableArray([

]);

self.populateFishing = function() { 
self.calcContent.push(calcItem('Shrimp','#',1,10));
self.calcContent.push(calcItem('Sardine','#',5,20));
self.calcContent.push(calcItem('Shark','#',110,76));
self.calcContent.push(calcItem('Sea Turtle','#',38,79));
self.calcContent.push(calcItem('Manta Ray','#',46,81));
    }
```

At the moment, it calculates for the first time perfectly, and it *appears* that when 'neededXp' is updated, it recalculates all values with the correct 'neededXp', but the computed observable for each index in the array reads the 'xp' from the last member of the array.

To clarify, when I update 'neededXp', all members 'need' are recalculated with the 'xp' from the *Manta Ray* value, rather than their respective indexes.

Probably something really obvious, hope someone can direct me though.

EDIT: After re-reading my code, I think I can see *why* it's happening, but I don't know how to fix. I don't know how to maintain the 'xp' value in the array, if that makes sense.

EDIT2: http://jsfiddle.net/sTnY7/
jsfiddle with reduced size arrays for usability. Hit the fish button to populate the table, then change the "Goal Level" to 6 for easiest demonstration of the problem. This is where the problem happens - all the "# Required" take the XP value from the last member of the array and recalculate. If Goal Level is 6, it shows 102.2 - where "Shrimp" should be 511, for example.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I am just guessing this - could it be the 'this' scoping issue? Could you try scoping this with 'self2' in calcItem i.e. 'var self2 = this;'?

Comment: No dice. I think the scoping is fine (could be wrong) because the initial calculation works fine (when I populate my table), but everything after that is broken.

On a different note, could it be a scoping problem in the sense that my calcItem function is within my calcModel function? i have seen people put it outside.

If I am to do that, how do I pass my neededXp for the calculation? include it on every .push()..?

speculating.

Comment: Could you share the markup or better, this sample on a jsfiddle? I'd like to play around a bit, if thats ok.

Comment: have editted with jsfiddle, but here it is anyway http://jsfiddle.net/sTnY7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - so I created a fiddle myself

http://jsfiddle.net/dD67p/2/

Had to make a couple of changes -

Scoping (as I suspected) - 
calcItem now looks like this:

```
function calcItem(name, image, xp, level) {
    var self2 = this;
    self2.name = name;
    self2.level = level;
    self2.xp = xp;
    self2.need = ko.computed(function () {
        var req = self.neededXp() / self2.xp;
        return req;
    });
```

Also, you missed the `new` while creating `calcItem` objects and pushing them to `calcContent`.

I changed `populateFishing` to look like

```
self.populateFishing = function () {
    self.calcContent.push(new calcItem('Shrimp', '#', 1, 10));
    self.calcContent.push(new calcItem('Sardine', '#', 5, 20));
    self.calcContent.push(new calcItem('Shark', '#', 110, 76));
    self.calcContent.push(new calcItem('Sea Turtle', '#', 38, 79));
    self.calcContent.push(new calcItem('Manta Ray', '#', 46, 81));
}
```

You can see the bound data change on updating the neededXp in this fiddle.